# softlayer billing order orderType

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When i get a getInvoices using Account API, there are orderType of billingItem.

it's orderType representation 'API', 'PORTAL','CONTROL' or Null value.

(in api describe "A simple keyname stating where a SoftLayer order originated from.")

What is it that these values mean exactly ?

API ->

PORTL ->

CONTROL ->

NULL ->

Answer (score 0):

These values mean from where the orders have been originating, for example:

> - API: Originating from API
> - CONTROL: Originating from Control Portal
> - PORTAL: Originating from Manage Portal
> - NULL: Null - No information available